# Parallel 0-10 VDC sensor read-out causes voltage drop

Tags: adc

I have an analogue anemometer (wind sensor) installed on my roof. This is connected to a logic device ([manufacturer PDF](https://partner.gira.de/data3/09131690.pdf)) to switch 230 Vac to protect blinds from heavy winds.

I want to digitise the signal of the sensor and connected a ADC-to-RS485 converter ([eletechsup R4AVA07](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001756319070.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.23a81e657wAAzO&algo_pvid=21c4eff6-a7e7-4f93-bae3-e7a6c8f6f90b&algo_exp_id=21c4eff6-a7e7-4f93-bae3-e7a6c8f6f90b-1&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000017589461301%22%7D&pdp_pi=-1%3B4.98%3B-1%3B-1%400.190000%3BEUR%3Bsearch-mainSearch)) module in parallel to the logic device.

If I measure the voltage coming from the roof sensor, I usually get around 2-4 V (depending on wind conditions.) As soon as I connect the ADC board, it drops to 100-130 mV.

I use input A7 & GND on the ADC board according to wiring diagram in parallel to the connector of the logic device (which is a black box for me, but knowing it expects a 0-10 V input I would assume the wiring should not interfere with internals.)

I triple-checked the wiring and specs (e.g. minimal 1 mA current needed) but somehow I'm out of options.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwKcqG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The anemometer outputs pulses, not an analog voltage. You need a specific interface for the anemometer.

Comment: The crappy mali-express ADC module takes a 4/20 mA input and not a voltage.

Comment: The anemometer is 0-10V and is not a counter. https://partner.gira.de/data3/05791390.pdf

Comment: @Andy aka yes I know the ADC module is not adhering to highest standards. But is supposed to do 0-5V, 0-10V and 4/20mA with a resistor. I assume its just broken. Even a CV source (battery) doesn’t seem to give a reading.  Have an alternative ADC module in the mail, waiting for arrival. Just wanted to validate my design idea isn’t broken by design. 

Answer (score 2):

Your statement: “If I measure the voltage coming from the roof sensor, I usually get around 2-4 V (depending on wind conditions.) As soon as I connect the ADC board, it drops to 100-130 mV.” Tells me that maybe the ADC circuit internal impedance/resistance is altering the total impedance/resistance of the circuit. You need somehow to match the impedance/resistance of both circuits (maybe an isolating low value capacitor in series between the anemometer + lead and the A7 input will solve that?)

Also, using the CV source (battery) may not have worked because the ADC is expecting a variable (AC) not constant (DC) voltage.

I will do some more tests with each unit, independently of each other, to identify their operation range (impedance/resistance, etc) and better understand how they work when connected.